# smooth efffect in flex

Tags: apache-flex, effect, smoothing, television

I'm using move effect in my project but It didn't worked as I expect. When moving the Label from right to left, It's not smoothly and I feel jerky when running. How can I resolved it, especially when I deploy in TV screen.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The jerky feeling might be caused of a too low **frames per second** (frame rate) refresh on the **TV** screen you mentioned. You might try lowering the **frameRate** attribute of **the application to match that of the TV** (25 or 24 frames per second I assume?).

http://algorizms.blogspot.com/2007/08/flex-framerate-attribute.html

Another thing you might try is to make the move effect with a bigger duration.

If non of these thing help then you might have to write the effect on your own by changing your components x and y on every(some of) the frames of your application (**ENTER_FRAME**).

Hope this helps,

Blaze

Comment: In addition to that, try to blur Label while it moves. This will increase smoothness at pixel level.